# WPF how to expose binding source as a resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources

I have a TabControl located in the ParentView. Inside that TabControl I have ChildView that contains a button with command bound to ParentViewModel's ICommand:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ParentView}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

Quite a few of these actually. Is there a way of creating UserControl resource from that RelativeSource and DataContext so I can declare my buttons more like that?:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source={StaticResource MyParentsDataContext}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

**Edit**

What I came up so far is this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <RelativeSource x:Key="Parent" AncestorType="{x:Type local:ParentView}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={StaticResource Parent}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

Slightly dryer and more readable, but still not sure how to get rid of `DataContext` if possible at all.

Comment: Why would you want to set the `Source` to an object? What you should do is to add a command property to the child view's `DataContext` and bind directly to this one. Or stick to your current approach.

Comment: My Child view's does not have specific ```DataContext```. Children are inheriting ```DataContext``` from the Parent. In my case Child is not a view per se, child could as well be declared in Parent. I just wanted to move a lot of xaml to separate UserControl so Parent is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything you like in application.current.resources.

It's rather like a sort of in memory dictionary with key of string and value of object.

You could therefore add an instance of a class in a resource dictionary merged in app.xaml:

```
  <local:AnyViewModel x:Key="VM"/>
```

If you need no parameters for this then you may find you never need to change that.

If there's more to this parent viewmodel then you can replace a dummy version.

If you then either merge in an instance from another resource dictionary with the same key in a more local scope or set it in code:

```
 Application.Current.Resources["VM"] = newInstance;
```

That then would replace what a binding would find in resources.

If you want to do that dynamically then there's a bit of a trick with the dynamicresource to bear in mind.

You'd need:

```
<Button DataContext="{DynamicResource VM}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{This is now a complication}">
```

If the VM doesn't need to be dynamic then you're OK with staticresource:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source={StaticResource VM}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

If that isn't convenient for some reason you could make the resource a viewmodel which implements inotifypropertychanged and the specific viewmodel you're interested a property of that:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding ParentViewmodel.MyCommand, Source={StaticResource VM}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

That would allow you to switch out ParentViewmodel on the command.